# Fetch Record of each rows and column

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-2.0

I have a gridview which displays the records in the below form:

```
Date                    Total Enrolled  Enrolled as Email   Enrolled as Text   
2/29/2012 12:00:00 AM   1               0                   1   
2/28/2012 12:00:00 AM   2               1                   1   
2/27/2012 12:00:00 AM   23              11                  12   
2/25/2012 12:00:00 AM   1               1                   0   
2/24/2012 12:00:00 AM   16              9                   7
```

Which displays the record using this query:

```
select created,
count(field1) Enrolled,
count(case field1 when 'E-mail' then 1 end) Enrolled_as_Email,
count(case field1 when 'Cell Phone' then 1 end) Enrolled_as_Cell,
(Select COUNT(*)
from tbl_TransactionDishout d
where d.created = c.created and
       d.DishoutResponseCode = '0000') Deals_Redeemed
from tblCustomer c
group by created
order by created
```

ASP.NET Code is as below:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GrdReport" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="1" DataKeyNames="Created" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
                ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" PageSize="100" 
                onrowdatabound="GrdReport_RowDataBound">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Created" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Created" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Total_Enrolled" HeaderText="Total Enrolled" SortExpression="Total_Enrolled" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Enrolled_as_Email" HeaderText="Enrolled as Email" SortExpression="Enrolled_as_Email" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Enrolled_as_Cell" HeaderText="Enrolled as Text" SortExpression="Enrolled_as_Cell" />
                </Columns>
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" Height="4" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ appSettings:DBConn %>"
                SelectCommand="select created, count(field1) Total_Enrolled, count(case field1 when 'E-mail' then 1 end) Enrolled_as_Email, count(case field1 when 'Cell Phone' then 1 end) Enrolled_as_Cell from tblCustomer group by created order by created desc">
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Now I want the number to be a hyperlink which redirect the page to some other page where it displays those records..
So how should it be done.?? What should I pass in query string such that I can recognize it on the redirected page..and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your linke would look like this...

http://address/page.aspx?parameter=value&nextparameter=value

http://localhost/newpage.aspx?email=0&text=1

in your asp.net page you can access query string like this

```
Request.QueryString["email"];

Request.QueryString["text"];
```

This is only one easy approach... If you build complex webapps you should take of more but this could get you started

if I have understand your question correct...

You should make sure that you encode the values to make them html safe...

EDIT: to construct your link use hyperlinkfield

```
<asp:hyperlinkfield datatextfield="UnitPrice"
        datatextformatstring="{0:c}"
        datanavigateurlfields="ProductID"
        datanavigateurlformatstring="~\details.aspx?ProductID={0}"          
        headertext="Price"
        target="_blank" />
```

to use multiple parameters comma seperate them like this

```
    <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="CategoryName" 
DataNavigateUrlFields="CategoryID,CategoryName,Description" 
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Learning.aspx?categoryID={0}&categoryName={1}&description={2}"
 />
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.aspx

then you need a 2nd page which dsiplays the details and queries the result based on the passed values...

Comment: What do you mean? Do you only have your query and no asp.net code at all?